# Cannot install hamster gem on RubyInstaller Windows environment

Tags: ruby, windows

Hamster installation fails with following error:

C:>gem install hamster
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
    Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/hamster-0.4.3/spec/hamster/experimental/mutable_set/add?_spec.rb

I was able to install other gems such as puma, ripl, sinatra, rest-client and ffi.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Most gems are not suited for Windows. Why not use a Linux? I got same error but not in Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download latest version from GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/hamstergem/hamster.git
```

Then you probably will have to change the version in `lib\hamster\version.rb` to build the gem.

```
module Hamster
  VERSION = "1.0.1" # <- modified 
end
```

Now you can build and install it.

```
cd hamster
gem build hamster.gemspec
gem install hamster
```

DevKit is required to build native extensions.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Just wondering, why the version needed to be changed? I'm all new here so I cannot up vote.

Comment: I got error `Invalid gemspec in [c:\hamster\hamster.gemspec]: Malformed version number string 1.0.1-rc3`